# Pandas way to keep int portion of a column of numbers in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) column of floats:

```
0       59.9179
1       50.3874
2       50.3874
3       55.0089
4        58.423
5       58.8227
6       55.2471
7       57.2266
8       46.4312
9       59.9097
10      57.1417
```

Is there a way in pandas to keep the integer portion of the number and discard the decimal, so the resulting column would look like:

```
0       59
1       50
2       50
3       55
4       58
5       58
6       55
7       57
8       46
9       59
10      57
```

I can see a way to do this for 1 number

```
>>> s = 59.9179
>>> i, d = divmod(s, 1)
>>> i
59
```

but not for a whole column in one go

Many thanks

Comment: It's working for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options:

1. Casting the column type (or even the whole dataframe):

   ```
   df[column] = df[column].astype(int)
   ```
2. Or using numpy's floor method (for positive floats as in your example)

   ```
   df[column] = np.floor(df[column])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` method by passing a **lambda** function.

```
df = df.apply(lambda row: int(row['second_column']), axis=1)
```

Another method is to use `astype` method.

```
df[second_column] = df[second_column].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column name is `col` then do the following:

```
df[col]=df[col].astype('int')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  use this:

```
df[your_column] = df[your_column].astype(int)
```

Or for the whole df:

```
df = df.astype(int)
```

Answer (score -1):

### To keep integer part use trunc() function as shown below.

**Easiest method** is to **use *trunc()* function on the column**.

```
df[col_name] = trunc(df[col_name])
```